# Creating map of Denmark using ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, denmark

I have installed the following two packages:

```
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
```

I have found code online to create a world map (see below).

How do I zoom the plot on a country level?

For example, [Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denmark).

```
ggplot()+
  borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If we look at `?borders` and, for more into, `?map`, we see that we may use the `regions` argument:

```
ggplot() + borders(regions = "Denmark", colour = "gray50", fill = "gray50")
```

[image]

Comment: Also, a very beautiful package for maps is leaflet: i.e `l <- leaflet() %>% setView(lat = 50.85045, lng = 4.34878, zoom=5) %>% addTiles(group="OSM")`

Comment: @Julius Vainora: Thanks. Can I add layers to this plot? For example if I find a data set with "state boundries"?

Comment: @David, yes, layers can be added, for instance `+ geom_point(data = data.frame(x = 12, y = 56), aes(x = x, y = y))` adds a point.

Comment: When using maps, you might want to add `coord_cartesian()`, so that the scale of the x and the y axes match.

Answer (score 11):

Get the bounds of Denmark in lat-long and use `coord_fixed`:

```
ggplot() + borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") + coord_fixed(xlim=c(7, 12), ylim=c(52, 58))
```

[image]

You can get the bounds from the `map` package:

```
> map("world", "Denmark", plot=FALSE)$range
[1]  8.121484 15.137110 54.628857 57.736916
```

And you might want to expand these a bit for nicer spacing and more context.

Comment: @ when I run ``map("world","Denmark",plot=FALSE)$range`` I get ``NULL``?

Comment: Odd. Does `map("world","Denmark")` produce a map of Denmark? What about "France" or "Belgium"? Is it using local country names ("Danmark")? Does `map("world")` draw a map? Does `map("world",plot=FALSE)$names` return a vector of country/region names? If those don't work, then that's very odd and you should ask a new Q or report a bug...

Comment: @ Spacedan: None of them work either ``NULL`` or error. But I can create the plots in the answers...

Comment: Start a new clean R session, do `library(maps)`, then try? Maybe you've got something masking the `maps::map` function. Probably `purrr::map`? Don't use `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: @ Spacedman: I think it is okay if I use maps::map. Maybe it thought the map function from the purrr package...

Comment: Most of [Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen) is not included...